# Paramiko sftp upload with ppk file

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I am trying to create a python script with Paramiko Lib to upload a file on sftp which uses a "ppk" file and a passphrase to connect.

Unfortunately I cant crack the document or found anything which can connect sftp with ppk files.

**Additional details:**
SFTP can manually be connected with Filezilla, WinSCP is not allowing it.

Here is the code I can go upto only. Please help!

```
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/key.ppk")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
c.connect( hostname = "ftp.example.com", username = "user", pkey = k,passphrase="somephrase" )
```

Well that's the least of the problems, I need to upload afterwards when it gets connected.

Comment: you can use puttygen to convert ppk to openssh which should work fine

Comment: Ahh ok, Got it. I was looking for document reference to directly use PPK files, now understood, it has to be converted first. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1):

i  suggest that you convert .ppk to .pem !
see :
[Conver ppk to pem](https://tecadmin.net/convert-ppk-to-pem-using-command/)

then like this :

```
import paramiko
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("mykey.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print "connecting"
c.connect( hostname = "www.host.com", username = "ubuntu", pkey = k )
print "connected"
commands = [ "/home/ubuntu/firstscript.sh", "/home/ubuntu/secondscript.sh" ]
for command in commands:
    print "Executing {}".format( command )
    stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read()
    print( "Errors")
    print stderr.read()
c.close()
```

Comment: Ok understood. It has to converted first and then use that converted file. Thanks @moetaz